# Manual backup for mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, backup, dropbox, tortoisehg, lan

I am using Mercurial with tortoiseHg, and I have few repositories around my computer (because i work with different languages at the same time).
I would like to have a backup of all my repositories that I would trigger manually (ideally with an icon on my desktop).
I am open to many backup solution, like using dropbox, or using another computer on the same network or both solutions at the same time.
Which is the best solution  and how can I implement it?
I am using windows 7

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7 (sorry I forgot to mention it on the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to import your repositories into a Mercurial hosting service like [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) and then use the built-in push feature of Mercurial to periodically copy your local changes to the remote clone. You can find instructions on how to import an existing repository into Bitbucket [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-UploadingorpushingaGitorMercurialprojecttoanemptyrepository).

Answer (score 2):

A repository hosting service like BitBucket will allow you to to not only backup your repositories but also get them off site giving you recovery options in case of a significant catastrophe plus allow you to easily share your work with others if you so desire.

If you just want to backup the repository, you can use any method you want (even just copying files) to grab a copy of the project's .hg directory.  At work, we use a central repository  on the corporate network that is backed up, fire and access protected.